# Detect SO_RCVTIMEO on socket when using select

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a C++ TCP socket server and I want to timeout a connection if there is no activity. I have tried to used 
rc = setsockopt(serversockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO , (char *) &timeout,sizeof(timeout));  to set a 200 second timeout.
I am using select to detect if there is data to be read but the socket timeout does  not seem to work or is not detected by select. 
Any advice on detecting the timeout would be appreciated 
Thank You
Regards

Comment: `select` has its own timeout, in the last parameter. Use that. `SO_RCVTIMEO` is documented to apply to blocking calls, which `select` is not.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: `SO_RCVTIMEO` does not apply to `select()`. `select()` can call tell you when to read, then you have to call `recv()`. `SO_RCVTIMEO` doesn't make sense in this scenario, since `recv()` will just return whatever is available without blocking. Unless you use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag, then `SO_RCVTIMEO` might have a chance of taking effect. Otherwise, call `recv()` without calling `select()` first, then `SO_RCVTIMEO` will definitely take effect